# How to long-press in android 4.1.2 and 4.2.2 using ADB?

Tags: adb, shell, scripts, input-methods

I discovered that the command below does not execute in android 4.1.2 and 4.2.2 but it executes from android 4.4+.

```
input touchscreen swipe x1 y1 x2 y2 [duration]
```

I am using my old android 4.1.2 and 4.2.2 in kiosk mode and I need my script to long-press on some areas but I can't get the above command to do the trick for me but it does work perfectly in my other android 4.4.2 and 4.4.4?
My question is, what files should I copy from my android 4.4.2 to my android 4.2.2 to get the above command to work in android 4.2.2 ?? Or is there any other means of doing it? 
NOTE: I don't need `sendevent` method please, I only need `input touchscreen swipe` method. Thanks

Comment: try */system/bin/input* binary from kk is running on jb (from */data/local/tmp*)

Comment: Sorry please, I did not understand what you said I should do with the input binary from KK. Can you elaborate better please?

Comment: adb push input /data/local/tmp; adb shell; cd /data/local/tmp; chmod a+x ./input; ./input

Comment: After pushing the KK input binary to /data/local/tmp how can I execute it from terminal because I learnt that it is the shell that searches /system/bin or /system/xbin for binaries when your script calls a binary

Comment: call binary with full (or relative) path

Answer (score -2):

Does the --longpress modifier works?

```
input keyevent --longpress ##
```

Comment: No it doesn't work in android 4.2.2. If I run `input` command it doesn't list `--longpress` as an available modifier, but does so in android 4.4.2+